Hanging multiple PEX lines along steel I-beam
I have an I-beam running along the middle of my house's basement, and I would like to attach three 1/2" PEX lines (for hot, cold, and unsoftened water) to the beam, and run them from one end to the other.
Here is a picture of the beam (beyond the wall is a finished room in the basement):

I'm having trouble finding hardware to attach multiple PEX lines to a metal beam. One PEX manufacturer has an installation manual which says that when running PEX along an I-beam, to attach the line(s) to the bottom of the beam, but there's no explanation of how to attach them, or why it would be important to put the lines on the bottom edge (I'd rather attach them to the top edge so they hang on one side of the beam and don't reduce ceiling height). I'm also able to find small C-clamps intended to hold conduit, but that would only work for one line, and I'm unsure if they'll cause friction on the PEX. What information or hardware am I missing?

If it helps, I'd be happy to upload a picture of the joist, or add links to the conduit clamps I found so far.

Pictures would definitely help, as you first call it an I-joist (which is an engineered wood product) and then say it's steel (so it's probably a steel I-beam, not a joist at all.)

There are a variety of steel beam clamps available—some spring-loaded, some threaded.  Do you want to put the lines above the bottom flange, or something?

Added a picture of the beam, as well as a link to the hardware I found that doesn't quite work.

I suppose it might depend on how picky your plumbing inspector (if any) is about doing it in a way that's specifically intended for pipe/tube support, but bridle rings (available in multiple sizes) mostly used for low-voltage communications cable would easily support three 1/2" tubes, and mate with beam clamps to mount on the flanges of an I-beam.

Image source, no endorsement implied

Image source, no endorsement implied

option A: Attach 3/4" plywood pieces to the web of the beam using self-drilling screws or powder-actuated nails then use regular pex saddles to attach the pex to the wood.  (can substitute MDF or OSB etc for plywood)
option B: drill holes though lumber (or cut grooves in it) to fit the pipes and then attach the lumber to the beam using self drilling screws etc.

Am thinking about doing something similar but without directly attaching to (or otherwise affecting) the steel i-beam.
The idea was to run a length of 2x4 within the cavity of the i-beam (to which the pex pipes could be attached in the usual manner and then fixing that 2x4 to a 2x3 frame surrounding the i-beam.
The underside of the frame around the i-beam could be osb/plywood to keep it square and more-or-less detached from the i-beam itself.

Two hole straps would work fine. I'd insulate all lines and use a 3-4" two hole strap going along the side. Drilling into the I beam to attach hanger supports will not affect the integrity of it. And remember plumbing code requires 1/2" pex to be supported every 32 inches.
